# Url loading error for image in runnable jar

Tags: java, url, jframe, icons

So, when I try the following code:

```
//Main Class

package com.mgflow58.Main;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage mainicon = null;
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Guppy's Adventure");
        window.add(new GamePanel());
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

        try {
            String mainurlstring = "icon.gif";
            URL mainurl = new URL(mainurlstring);
            try {
                mainicon = ImageIO.read(mainurl);
                window.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(mainicon).getImage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I get the following error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: icon.gif
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mgflow58.Main.Game.main(Game.java:28)
```

The file icon.gif is in the root folder, and I even tried copying it into src/com/mgflow58/Main where the class executing the code is in. What am I doing wrong? I simply can not set an image icon no matter which methods I try and I have been trying to find an answer for a while already.

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified the answer to something from a previous question. I have done a stupid mistake somewhere, but now I wrote a line anew and the problem was fixed. This is how I accessed icon.gif:

```
//Main Class

package com.mgflow58.Main;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage mainicon = null;
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Guppy's Adventure");
        window.add(new GamePanel());
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

        window.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(Game.class.getResource("/icon.gif")).getImage());

    }

}
```